# Fabric / Crashlytics - Enhance bug tracking

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using Crashlytics to track bug in my iOS app. Every time I release a new build on the store, I upload the dSYMs file to Crashlytics as explained [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html)

My problem is that most of the time I am still unable to get readable stack traces. 
An example is the following:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001000a7400
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AppName                   0x1000a7400 specialized static FormUtils.formatStringToRealmDate(dateString : String) -> Date + 4295750656
1  AppName                    0x100038dd0 specialized MenuTableViewController.(getInbox() -> ()).(closure #1) (FormUtils.swift)
2  AppName                    0x1000382d0 partial apply for MenuTableViewController.(getInbox() -> ()).(closure #1) (MenuTableViewController.swift)
```

How can I read that? The only thing I understand is the function that is causing the problem: FormUtils.formatStringToRealmDate but I have no clue why it is happening.

Is there a way to improve this?
Thank you for any help!